# MudAutocomplete is null or empty Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

I have a problem, I am using the Mudblazor library and the MudAutocomplete component. The problem is that when I don't find anything in the field and click to confirm, I get an error that the object is null. How to protect yourself against this. I thought about using the disable option on the button but I don't know how to check if the object is null. My code:

```
<MudDialog>
    <DialogContent>

         <MudItem >
            <MudPaper Class="pa-4">

                <MudAutocomplete Required="true" RequiredError="Pole muis być uzupełnione!" @ref="RefEntryField" T="OptymalizationModels" Label="Indeks - Nazwa Towaru" @bind-Value="elemecik" SearchFunc="@Search2" ToStringFunc="@(e=> e==null?null : $"{e.indeks_compApps} - {e.Nazwa_ERPXL}")" ShowProgressIndicator="true" ProgressIndicatorColor="Color.Default" CoerceText="true" ResetValueOnEmptyText="false" />
            </MudPaper>
        </MudItem>

    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
        <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled"  Color="Color.Error" OnClick="Cancel">Anuluj</MudButton>
        <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Save" Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="Replace" Disabled="false">Zamień</MudButton>
    </DialogActions>    
</MudDialog>
code {
    IEnumerable<OptymalizationModels> lista;
    OptymalizationModels elemecik;
    OptymalizationModels tmp_elemecik;
    [CascadingParameter] MudDialogInstance MudDialog { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public int id { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public int srcdoc { get; set; }
    private MudAutocomplete<OptymalizationModels> RefEntryField;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        tmp_elemecik = new OptymalizationModels();
        lista = await Task.Run(() => oS.GetListOkucInWarehouse());
        tmp_elemecik = await Task.Run(() => oS.GetONEOkucia(srcdoc, id));
    
    }
    private async Task<IEnumerable<OptymalizationModels>> Search2(string value)
    {

        // In real life use an asynchronous function for fetching data from an api.
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        // if text is null or empty, don't return values (drop-down will not open)
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            return lista;
        return lista.Where(x => x.Nazwa_ERPXL.Contains(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || x.indeks_compApps.Contains(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

    }
    void Submit() => MudDialog.Close(DialogResult.Ok(true));
    void Cancel() => MudDialog.Cancel();
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender) { await RefEntryField.FocusAsync(); }
    }
    private async Task Replace()
    {
     
        oS.UPDATEReplace(srcdoc, id, elemecik.Nazwa_ERPXL, elemecik.indeks_compApps, elemecik.jednostka_compApps, elemecik.ilosc_compApps, elemecik.gid_numer_compApps, elemecik.magazyn, elemecik.regal, elemecik.polka, elemecik.indeks_compApps,tmp_elemecik.indeks_compApps);
        Submit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set the `Disabled` attribute to `elemcik == null`

So you would have

```
<MudButton ... Disabled="@(elemcik == null)">Zamień</MudButton>
```

I suggest using the form component with validation. So you can give the user the feedback that `elemcik` has to be selected.

https://mudblazor.com/components/form#simple-form-validation

Or you could check for the object not being null in your `Replace` method and by using the `Error` and `ErrorText` attribute of `MudAutocomplete` you can then display the error.

```
private async Task Replace()
{
    if(elemcik == null)
    {
        RefEntryField.Error = true;
        RefEntryField.ErrorText = "Please select one"
    }
    else
    {
        oS.UPDATEReplace(srcdoc, id, elemecik.Nazwa_ERPXL, elemecik.indeks_compApps, elemecik.jednostka_compApps, elemecik.ilosc_compApps, elemecik.gid_numer_compApps, elemecik.magazyn, elemecik.regal, elemecik.polka, elemecik.indeks_compApps,tmp_elemecik.indeks_compApps);
        Submit();
    }
}
```